# error in onUpdateReceived(Update update) method

Tags: telegram-bot

I try to override telegram bot method onUpdateReceived(Update update), but for some reason is
not possible .setChatId (see screen shot). Any idea?

```
public void onUpdateReceived(Update update) {
      // We check if the update has a message and the message has text
    if (update.hasMessage() && update.getMessage().hasText()) {
        // Set variables
        String message_text = update.getMessage().getText();
        long chat_id = update.getMessage().getChatId();

        SendMessage message = new SendMessage().setChatId(chat_id).setText(message_text);
        try {
            execute(message); // Sending our message object to user
        } catch (TelegramApiException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jvtvJ.png)

Answer (score 0):

This is because you should not stack those SendMessage methods. Instead,

```
SendMessage message = new SendMessage();
message.setChatId(chat_id);
message.setText(message_text);
```

The reason you're getting an error is because .setText() method returns void but you'are trying to store the return into a SendMessage object.